# Paypal Sandbox - "Invalid data provided" when try to add tracking info

Tags: api, rest, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to add tracking information for PayPal transactions and use [examples](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/tracking/v1/) from docs:

```
curl -v -X PUT https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers/8MC585209K746392H-443844607820 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <my access token>" \
-d '{
  "transaction_id": "8MC585209K746392H",
  "tracking_number": "443844607820",
  "status": "SHIPPED",
  "carrier": "FEDEX"
}
```

But the response is:

```
{"errors":[{"name":"INVALID_TRANSACTION_ID","message":"Invalid data provided","debug_id":"4bec***8348","details":[{"field":"#/transaction_id","value":"8MC585209K746392H","location":"body","issue":"INVALID_TRANSACTION_ID"}]}]}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that is not a payment transaction ID from a capture. Perhaps you are mistakenly passing an Order ID -- which is only used during approval and not persisted nor useful after capture.

The PayPal transaction ID is in the capture response at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`